# How to resize the font inaccordance with the div size....?

Tags: html

If the name is like "david" it comes within the allotted space....
but if the name is like "john pal abraham desouza" the allotted space increases automatically..

So i need to have the name occupied in the allotted space by auto resizing the font..
Suggest me a solution..

Comment: If you can only use HTML (or CSS) then you are out of luck. Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: what if they have "john pal abraham desouza the third and most righteous" Resizing your text to me sounds like a bad idea. If you started at 10pt with john where would the above name leave you 6pt. I am not sure most people could read it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [resize font to fit in a div (on one line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401136/resize-font-to-fit-in-a-div-on-one-line)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to check the length of the string and guess at a suitable font-size, check the rendered width and then adjust again if necessary.

As @Kieran says above, it's not going to be fool-proof - if a name is very long the font-size will be really small. Also, if there are no spaces in a long name, then the text won't wrap over two lines. However, that's a bit of an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a hidden dummy `div` to do the checking

By using a hidden (using `visibility: hidden`) and absolutely positioned `div` with same font CSS settings and copied content, you can easily change font sizes and check `div` width. When it exceeds certain size you can use the last valid value on your original `div`. This will avoid visual change of your fonts and content repositioning and recalculation so it will work faster. This will also avoid problems with long non-spaced words.

The same question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3401136/75642) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401136/resize-font-to-fit-in-a-div-on-one-line/3401187#3401187).