# Change Font Size to automatically fit Div's height/width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [resize font to fit in a div (on one line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401136/resize-font-to-fit-in-a-div-on-one-line)

I'm trying to make text automatically resize to fully fit inside a static 200 width 100 height div.

Basically I want the maximum font-size available depending on the lenght of the content fed in the div.

I'd like to use the least amount of Javascript/Jquery possible.

Comment: Great! ...and what mark-up would you be using to contain this text? And what have you tried so far, that didn't work? And, because I had to ask **those** questions, I offer you the obligatory from-Jon-Skeet [great question tutorial](http://tiny.url/so-hints). Have a read, it's good advice.

Comment: [This jQuery plugin](http://fittextjs.com/) does exactly what I was looking for at the time. Hope it helps for whoever's still looking at this.

Comment: If that plug-in answers your question, post that as an answer, and then accept that answer.