# How to make this loading overlay effect responsive?

Tags: css, overlay, css-transitions, font-awesome

I'm trying to do a loading overlay effect with an rotating icon in the middle. I use [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#spinning).
So I coded this: **http://jsfiddle.net/eys3d/7/**

It works, but I'm trying to make it responsive. I mean, when the section size decreases, the spin size will decrease too (remaining centered). An if the size of the section increases, the oposite.

I tried to use `em` units, but I didn't get the result I expected.

Is this the best way to do it? How I can make it responsive?

**CSS**

```
section {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
}
#overlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999999999;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#overlay i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.spin-big {
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
.spin-normal {
    font-size: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-top: -22.5px;
    margin-left: -22.5px;
}
.spin-small {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div id="overlay"> 
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin spin-big"></i>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div id="overlay"> 
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin spin-normal"></i>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div id="overlay"> 
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin spin-small"></i>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any tip, advice or help will be appreciated, and If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you won't try to use `display:table` attribute to your overlay div and `display:table-cell` to fontawesome `i` class? as below:

```
#overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#overlay i {
   display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eys3d/9/)

Comment: Thanks! Cool way to do it! And what about the responsive size of the icon? do you have any idea? Why this does not work? http://jsfiddle.net/eys3d/13/ What I'm looking for is that the size of the icon will depend of the size of #overlay.

Comment: As far as I know, technically it is not possible to adjust font size according to the parent width. plz head over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358181/resize-font-size-according-to-div-size  to get more detail. You can use media query conditioned font sizes to get different sizes on different viewport width.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for good effect

```
.loading 
{
 pointer-events: all;
 z-index: 99999;
 border: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 cursor: wait;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this looking for a similar solution.

The only way to responsively change the font-size would be through media queries.

I.e:

```
@media min-device-width: 300px{
    font-size: 8px;
}

@media min-device-width: 480px{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

ext..

Answer (score -1):

```
-----------div in Layout Page---------------
 <div class="loading-bg" id="dvSpinner">
        <img src="~/Areas/Images/loader.gif">
    </div>
----------css-----------
.loading-bg {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 5000;
    width: 100%;
}
.loading-bg img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 46%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}


-------------html------------
<div class="appendInputFieldForUAIHiddenDiv"
                     id="appendInputFieldForUAIHiddenDiv">

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrimaryEmail, new { @class = "form-control enter-email-FPHidden-div", id = "email-address-entered", name = "email-address-entered" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryEmail)

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit-button-FPHidden" onclick="submitbuttonFPHidden()">
                        @ASRP.Resources.Resource.Submit
                    </button>
                </div>

--------------scripts--------------------------

function submitbuttonFPHidden() {


    var username = $('#email-address-entered').val();
    if (username == null || username == "") {
        document.getElementById("email-address-entered").style.borderColor = "#ff0232";
        return false;
    }

    if (!validateEmail(username)) {
        document.getElementById("email-address-entered").style.borderColor = "#ff0232";
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('dvSpinner').style.display = "block";
    $.ajax({
        url: "../User/ForgotPassword",
        data: { email: username },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        error: function (error, msg) {
            $('div#dvSpinner').hide();
            return false;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {


                if (data.emailSent == "Successful") {
                    document.getElementById('FPHiddenDivContainer').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('entered-email-address').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('entered-email-address-para').innerHTML = document.getElementById('email-address-entered').value;
                    document.getElementById('PwdMsgNew').style.display = "none";

                }
                else if (data.emailSent == "Failure")
                {
                    document.getElementById('FPHiddenDivContainer').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('entered-email-address').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('entered-email-address-para').innerHTML = document.getElementById('email-address-entered').value;
                    document.getElementById('PwdMsg').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('lblThankYou').style.display = "none";

                }


            }
            else {
                var ddlLangValue = $('#ddlLangs').val();
                setCookie("culture", ddlLangValue, 31536e3);
                var resources = {}; // Global variable.

                (function ($) {

                    $.getJSON("Resource/GetResources", function (data) {
                        resources = data;
                        alert(resources.fpUnabletoProcessReq);
                    });
                })(jQuery);
            }
            document.getElementById('dvSpinner').style.display = "none";
        }

    });
    return true;
}
```