# Font-size depends on div width and height

Tags: html, css

Consider the following markup and styles:

```
<div>
    Some text Some text Some text 
</div>

div{
    width: 100px;
}
```

How can I do that the text-content of div have a font-size's property value such that there is maximum font-size value in which text-content of div lie on one line entirely? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96daR/)

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401136/resize-font-to-fit-in-a-div-on-one-line

Comment: There is no *simple* pure-CSS solution. You will either have to resort to Javascript and live knowing that clients with Js disabled won't see what you expect them to or create a series of media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="text_container">whatever text you want</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    background:cyan;
    width:200px;
}
#text_container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var container = $("#container"),
text_container = $("#text_container"),
start_size = 100,
container_width = container.width();

text_container.css('font-size', start_size + 'px');


while (text_container.width() > container_width) {
    text_container.css('font-size', start_size--+'px');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpkpy/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
div{
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

By setting a minimum width you ensure that the div never gets small enough to collapse the text to multiple lines.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/96daR/4/

Comment: Though this way the text won't adjust to eventual width specification on the div.

Comment: Simple css won't help in this case. You will have to use java script to find the required width and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Give a id to the div, say `id="myDiv"`

Get height using one of this

javascript:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
h=myDiv.clientHeight;
h=myDiv.scrollHeight;
h=myDiv.offsetHeight;
```

or in jquery:

```
h=$("#myDiv").height();
h=$("#myDiv").innerHeight();
h=$("#myDiv").outerHeight();
```

Next set the font-size using this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.font-size=h+"px";
```