# Is there a better way to change the font size of a textarea depending on the current text length?

Tags: jquery, css, textarea, font-size, string-length

I have a textarea. If there are less than 20 characters in the textarea, the font size must gets bigger (with a class name). If the length is 20 characters or longer, the textarea gets no special treatment regarding  the font size.

This code **works**, but I'm worried on the browser performance. There are dozens of other processes working around the textarea as the user is typing, and this is definitely a nice-to-have feature. Any other ways I could optimize the constant checking everytime the user types a new letter?

```
$('#text').keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length < 20) {
        $(this).addClass('bigger');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('bigger');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think there is a CSS only solution. And for the `jQuery` solution using `change()` instead of `keyup()` would be better in my opinion

Comment: I think that you should carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945594/css-calc-on-font-size-changing-font-size-based-on-container-size

Comment: Thanks for the feedback