# Whitespace nowrap text fit div

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with fixed width and a quite long text. This long text is set to appear in
one line via `white-space: no-wrap`. The problem is, that I can't figure out how to make the font size of this text fit into the div (without making breaks to the text). Could anyone help please?

Example layout:

```
<div style="width: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap">This is a too long text to normally fit in</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="width: 100px; max-width: 100px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
   <span style="white-space: nowrap">This is a too long text to normally fit in</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why it has been chosen as the best answer ? It cuts the text with "...". The questioner wanted `to make the font size of this text fit into the div (without making breaks to the text)` Really wierd

Comment: Adracus wanted some text and remaining text as(...) in that fixed size div. He didn't want to adjust every thing in that div by reducing or increasing font size.

Comment: Lol ? Read his first message again that's all the contrary

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7A2Cn/)**

css:

```
.truncate {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Text will be in 1 line but in the above css code you can see dots(...) if it exceeds specified width

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to add some library in your project, this one would do the trick :

https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill

You would add in javascript :

```
$('.truncate').textfill({ widthOnly: 100px });
```

And you also need to keep the css attribute

```
.truncate{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set font size  `<span style="font-size:17px;white-space:
nowrap;">This is a too long text to normally fit in</span>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that another guy has the exact same request as yours. Have a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401136/resize-font-to-fit-in-a-div-on-one-line) where several jQuery/CSS solutions have been found.