# CSS3 vw for font-size : what does it mean

Tags: css

Definition says `1vw = 1% of viewport width`. But I don't get it what does it mean when used with `font-size`? For instance what does it mean if I set:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 10vw;
}
```

I thought that if I have `h1` with 10 characters it would take 100% of viewport, but it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font-size refers to the **vertical** size of the font not character width

See the demo below for how they react differently.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 10vw;
}
h1:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<h1>MY HEADER</h1>

<h1>MY HEADER</h1>
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hitengal/c8qe6yon/1/)

Comment: Thanks, so it there any way to compute vw so it is guaranteed that text is always displayed in one line (provided i know text length)?

Comment: Nope...not as far as I know. That requires Javascript...something like [**FitText.js**](http://fittextjs.com/)

Comment: Also see this [**previous question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401136/resize-font-to-fit-in-a-div-on-one-line)

Comment: @dragonfly -  seems potentially possible, if you knew the text wouldn't change you could set the vw unit to fit it in more easily, or you could use media queries - or, you could use a monospaced font where the character width is in a fixed ratio with the height

Answer (score 2):

As Paulie_D stated:

> Font-size refers to the vertical size of the font not character width.

If you're looking for the width of the character, you might want to look at [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) (for the thickness of a character) or [`font-kerning`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning) (for the spacing between characters).

Answer (score 2):

the `vw` unit is based on the width of the viewport.

`1vw` is 1% of the browser viewport width. (`vh` is the corresponding value for height)

This means if the viewport is `600px` wide then `10vw` is `60px` and that's how high your font will be

It also means that dimensions, including heights, can be set relative to the width of the screen, which is very useful for maintaining aspect ratios. This means your font size will respond to the size of the viewport, something which you [can't do with a font any other way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

[It's not supported in all cases](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), so it's good to provide a pixel fallback, like this:

```
height: 100px; /* over-ridden if vw can be interpreted */
height: 10vw; /* ignored if not understood */
```