# Styled Component fluid type

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sc-fluid-type-g6ww15?file=styles.ts)

It a simple react app where I am using styled components to create fluid type

I have the function from this article - https://nilsb.org/2019-02-12-sass-mixins-in-styled-components/

Currently the type is 48px up to 600px, it then scales up to 98px and at 800px and stays that size

This is what I want but currently the type size jumps down to a smaller size at 600px and then starts to scale up

Is it possible with this code to stop the type jumping in size at 600px and 800px

```
export function flexUnit(
  amount: number,
  minFont: number,
  maxFont: number,
  unit = "vw",
  prop = "font-size",
  minBreak: number,
  maxBreak: number
) {
  const minBreakpoint = minBreak;
  const maxBreakpoint = maxBreak;
  const dimension = unit === "vw" ? "width" : "height";

  return `
    @media (min-${dimension}: ${minBreakpoint}px) {
      ${prop}: ${amount}${unit};
      color: red;
    }

    ${
      maxFont
        ? `
        @media (min-${dimension}: ${maxBreakpoint}px) {
        ${prop}: ${maxFont}px;
      }
    `
        : ""
    }

    ${prop}: ${minFont}px;
    color: green;
  `;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**8vw would be 48px at 600 min-width.** So, it would scale up just fine till 800 min-width without any reduce in size after 600.

**5vw would be 30px at 600 min-width** which is causing the smaller size and then scale up to 98px at 800 min-width.

From the demo:

```
    const StyledHeadline = styled.p`
  ${flexUnit(8, 48, 96, "vw", "font-size", 600, 800)}
`;
```

calculation guide:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754518/12618221